# Can I copy specific lines from long text field to other fields

Tags: process-builder, long-text-area

I need to copy data from a long text field (source field a) into 3 other fields:
field b = lines 1-40 of source field a
field c = lines 41-80 of source field a
field d = lines 81-end of source field a

hoping there is a way in process builder to write a formula for so I don't need to ask for a trigger.

Comment: Process Builder isn't particularly well-suited for the task that you propose. The Formula language advanced enough to easily find, as you say, the 40th line of text. Even if you built such a formula, and it allowed it, it would use probably 100 times more CPU time than just using a trigger.

Comment: You can't bring long text area fields into formulas so that eliminates formula, workflow field update, and I think process builder as they all use the same formula building functionality so I assume that limit is spread across those features. This feels like a trigger use case.

Answer (score 1):

I have created 3 fields in Account SObject:

- **Long Text Area** *(text area long field)*
- **Text B** *(text field)*
- **Text C** *(text field)*

And created a Process Builder in Account SObject:

[image: Process Builder]

I'm updating the fields **Text B** & **Text C** when I change the value of **Long Text Area**. 
For example:

- I'm using **LEFT([Account].Long_Text_Area__c, 40)** to assign the first 40th characters to the **Text B** field.
- **RIGHT([Account].Long_Text_Area__c,40)** to **Text C**.

Result:

[image: Restult on change]

EDIT:

Take a look this documentation to operate with TEXT in formulas:
[Formula Operators and Functions: TEXT](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=0#text_functions)

Comment: Thanks both for the input. Figured but never hurts to ask.

Comment: OP is looking for the 41st line, not 41st character

Comment: yes thanks so much for trying but was looking for line. I appreciate the attempt.